# Issues with MailCore2 and Undefined symbols for arm64

Tags: objective-c, mailcore2

I have integrated MailCore2 into my Project as described on the projects gitHub-Page. I've done so using PODS and followed all their instructions regarding Standard C++ Compiler Settings, additional Linker-Flags etc. 
While building for the actual device (not simulator) I get

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>     "_res_9_ns_initparse", referenced from:
>         mailcore::MXRecordResolverOperation::main() in libMailCore-ios.a(MCMXRecordResolverOperation.o)
>     "_res_9_search", referenced from:
>         mailcore::MXRecordResolverOperation::main() in libMailCore-ios.a(MCMXRecordResolverOperation.o)
>     "_res_9_ns_parserr", referenced from:
>         mailcore::MXRecordResolverOperation::main() in libMailCore-ios.a(MCMXRecordResolverOperation.o)
>     "_res_9_ns_sprintrr", referenced from:
>         mailcore::MXRecordResolverOperation::main() in libMailCore-ios.a(MCMXRecordResolverOperation.o)
>     "_res_9_dn_expand", referenced from:
>         mailcore::MXRecordResolverOperation::main() in libMailCore-ios.a(MCMXRecordResolverOperation.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any help, idea, hint or tipp is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need to change the documentation of MailCore2 to match it.
You need to link with -lresolv (add it to "Other Flags" in the build settings).